# When I use babel to compile js, Proxy is not defined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

When I use babel to compile js, the config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var commonsPlugin = new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common.js');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        Index: './index.js',
        Test: './test.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: '[name].js' // Template based on keys in entry above
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
              test: /\.js(x?)$/,
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
              }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [commonsPlugin]
};
```

My entry js is just `console.log(new Proxy());`, in chrome will call an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Proxy is not defined`.

I'm sure `js` has been compiled, but why `Proxy` is not defined after babel compiling?

Comment: Have you tried babel-plugin-proxy ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proxies are currently unsupported by babeljs.

From their [website](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#proxies):

> **Unsupported feature**
>   Due to the limitations of ES5, Proxies cannot be transpiled or polyfilled. See support in [various JavaScript engines](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Proxy).

Answer (score 1):

Try experimental Node Module `babel-plugin-proxy`.

> npm install babel-plugin-proxy --save-dev

Note: It is not suitable for production environments because performance impact is huge.

**Reference:**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-proxy
https://github.com/krzkaczor/babel-plugin-proxy